# Remove whitespace before and after all input fields on the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a page with a huge form, many input fields. Sometimes our customers copy paste their info into this form and in the process, some whitespace are pasted into the form.

I want to be able to remove ALL whitespace before and after the values they put in the form fields.

For instance, I want `'   some thing     '` to become `'some thing'`.

Preferably I want to trigger this stripping when they leave the form field, that is, on blur.

How can I do this with jQuery or vanilla JS?

Comment: `on()` `blur` event on `input`, `trim()` the `val()` and set it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2L2hwssf/)

```
$('form').on('blur', 'input[type="text"], textarea', function() {
    // ES6
    // $(this).val((i, value) => value.trim());

    // ES5
    $(this).val(function(i, value) {
         return value.trim();
    });
});
```

Comment: This not only works for spaces, but additional trailing/leading line breaks too.